# EOFError after exporting program through Platypus

Tags: python, pycharm, platypus

Hi everyone I was trying to export the following code into a standalone app for Max on platypus:

```
import time

date = time.strftime("%y-%m-%d")
entries = []
entries.append(date + '\n')

while len(entries) < 8:
    entry = input("Type positive entry: ")
    entries.append(entry + '\n')
    for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
        entry = entry.strip('\n')
        row = f"{index}-{entry}"
        print(row)

def write_entries(entries_arg, filepath=date):
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(entries_arg)

write_entries(entries, date)

print("Goodbye and have more lovely experiences")
```

The code executes fine in PyCharm, but in platypus when starting the program it outputs:

```
​Type positive entry: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adminPrivat/python/7positive/7positives.app/Contents/Resources/script", line 8, in <module>
    entry = input("Type positive entry: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I am a little lost, where does the error originate if it executes fine on pycharm? Is it Platypus?